# Data Recording to simple text file

Tags: ros, rosbag, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a newbie here, just started working on ROS a week ago. Is there any way to record /save some data into a simple text file directly from the server or client?
I want to record the request received by the server, alternatively can anybody give example of this implemented by rosbag ?
The basic c++ methods of fstream and ofstream do not work in ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12474/data-recording-to-simple-text-file/) by [sj haque](https://answers.ros.org/users/1584/sj-haque/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2011-12-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. See [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/2291/how-can-i-use-bag-file-data-in-matlab#3799) question for how to convert ROS messages to text file from the command line.
2. [Here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Code%20API) is a good introduction to the rosbag API.
3. `fstream` and `ofstream` do work in ROS. All ROS nodes are still C++ executables. I've used `fstream` and `ofstream` many times for simple logging in my ROS nodes.
4. ROS also logs all ROS print statements (ROS_INFO) to log files. Mine are located in `~/.ros/log`. Files called `{node}-{number}-stdout.log` contain this information.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-12-28**:
Depending on the task at hand, maybe the simplest solution is: rostopic echo /mytopic > textfile